# Java - How to write a method that scans from text file

Tags: java, methods

I need to be able to have a method scan a line from a file and store this, so that in the driver class the method can be called to store the next line of the file, and then the  `toString()` method of the class can be used to print out the what was scanned. How would I do this?

Comment: You need to show the code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read a text file using java.util.Scanner

```
File file = new File("file.txt");

try {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean a normal .txt file so have a look at this previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: this should be a comment.